# How to index MongoDB multivalued field into Solr 5.3.0

Tags: solr

I have mongodb documents like this,,

```
 { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5993d55cebb06d20f08521ad"), 
    "LoginInfoId" : NumberInt(410), 
    "EstablishmentName" : "xyz", 
    "ShopCategory" : "Crockery", 
    "likes" : NumberInt(21), 
    "ShopCats" : [ 1,5,3 ]
    }

    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5993d55cebb06d20f088871ad"), 
    "LoginInfoId" : NumberInt(411), 
    "EstablishmentName" : "abc", 
    "ShopCategory" : "Crockery", 
    "likes" : NumberInt(51), 
    "ShopCats" : [ 1,8,9 ]
    }
```

I need to index the field `ShopCats` into a solr field as comma separated value 
like this,

> "ShopCats" : [ 1,2,3 ]

I need to use these values to do **filterquery** in solr search

I have tried with some schema field definitions

```
<field name="ShopCats" type="commaDelimited" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />



<fieldType name="commaDelimited" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=",\s*" />
      </analyzer>
     </fieldType>
```

Still the MongoDb document field `ShopCats` is not indexing into `solr`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use a Mongo connector, if yes then Mongo connectors unwinds Arrays so the below

```
 { 
"_id" : ObjectId("5993d55cebb06d20f08521ad"), 
"LoginInfoId" : NumberInt(410), 
"EstablishmentName" : "xyz", 
"ShopCategory" : "Crockery", 
"likes" : NumberInt(21), 
"ShopCats" : [ 1,5,3 ]
}
```

Will be changed to below before indexing

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5993d55cebb06d20f08521ad"), 
"LoginInfoId" : NumberInt(410), 
"EstablishmentName" : "xyz", 
"ShopCategory" : "Crockery", 
"likes" : NumberInt(21), 
"ShopCats.0" : 1,
"ShopCats.1" : 5,
"ShopCats.2" : 3
}
```

This will happen whenever there is a sub document, and Solr doesn't have he "sub-document" support/
You might be able to get around this with the copyField directive in your schema.xml.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes,,,iam using mongo connector. i have around 40 ShopCats values, if i use copfield then i should declare every 40 ShopCats and then copy to a single field. is that a good practise ?

Comment: @vampo458 I wouldn't comment on the best practice. But if you are connecting to Mongo using Java and extract those fields and use a SolrJ to index then you can overcome this situation. Also accept an answer if you find it helpful

Comment: I am working in PHP, Mongodb and solr, can i do the same with PHP solr class?